# Java: How to allow UDP socket program to receive and send with blocking I/O?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I am just fiddling around with making a UDP chat program that simply allows messages to be sent between two clients.  I am using the DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket classes.  The issue that I'm running into is when one client is waiting to receive a Datagram from the other client, using receive, then I can't send any messages with that client as its I/O is blocked, so my current version only allows one message back and forth at a time.  What I'm trying to accomplish it to allow the receive method to listen and run separately from the sending portion of the code so that the users can send as many messages as they want without waiting for a reply.  Any advice for examples would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two threads at each end, one to receive messages (and display them), and another to receive user input and send those messages.

Comment: Okay, perfect.  One other follow-up question.  Is it safe to create one socket at each end and use that socket in both the thread for sending and the thread for receiving, or should each thread be using its own socket.  My knowledge is low on this, so I'm just wondering if this would conflict if theoretically a client receives a message and went to send a message at the exact same moment.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1712917 yes, you can (and should) use one socket at each end and share it between the threads.